# coord_cartesian: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, posixct

I'm a bit stuck in ggplot due to the use of 'coord_cartesian'. A short extract of the code that crashes is like this:

```
year  = as.character(2011)
time1 = paste(year,'-01-01 00:00', " %Y-%m-%d %H:%M ",tz='UTC',sep = '')
time2 = paste(year,'-01-31 00:00', " %Y-%m-%d %H:%M ",tz='UTC',sep = '')

xmin = as.POSIXct(time1,tz='UTC')
xmax = as.POSIXct(time2,tz='UTC')

xlim = c(xmin,xmax)
ylim = c(0,80)
```

........................

Why doesnt the following line work:

```
ggplot(meltdf,aes(x=date,y=value,color=variable,group=variable)) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=xlim,ylim,expand = F)
```

Variables are:

> str(meltdf)
> 'data.frame': 26280 obs. of  3 variables:
> date    : POSIXct, format: "2011-01-01 00:00:00" "2011-01-01 01:00:00" ...
> variable: Factor w/ 3 levels "EBAS","EBAS (valid)",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
> value   : num  32.9 32.6 32.2 32 33.5 ...
> and

Whatever I try I get the message: Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

I simply want a time series plot restricted in time by the xlim

Comment: Hi there and welcome to stack overflow. Could I convince you to post the `dput(your_data_snippet)` instead of the `str()` output?

Comment: Oh, dput creates a very long output, I can put it on an accessible txt-file if needed, but the main output is like this: 
structure(list(date = structure(c(1293840000, 1293843600, 1293847200, 
1293850800, 1293854400, 1293858000, 1293861600, 1293865200, 1293868800, ...
,class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, ...
, .Label = c("EBAS", "EBAS (valid)", "NOAA"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(32.8571070594485, 32.6261188569367, 32.164142451913, ...
, row.names = c(NA, -26280L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Thanks! I tried to reproduce the issue, but I cannot trigger the error. What I tried was appending observations to the `variable` and `value` columns to match the length of the `date` column. Then I ran the code without any error, and it produced a plot.

Comment: Many thanks! Finally I got it right. Seemed to be caused by a mix of POSIXct and Date variables.